# Facebook Connect: difference between App Domains and Website with Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

i'm implementing a Facebook Connect and i don't understand the difference between App Domains and Website with Facebook Login.
What is the advantage or disadvantage in put site url in Website with Facebook Login or in App Domains? I've a site that has many alias.I see that  if i put in app domains my aliases Facebook Connect works correctly, but i want to understand better the difference.

Bye,
Lorenzo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Site URL**

If you want to integrate your website with the facebook, you certainly have to tell facebook the URL to your site where you want to integrate! So obviously, this field is mandatory if you want to integrate your website with fB.

**App Domains**

Not mandatory to mention the app domain in the settings. This is just used to lock down the domains and sub-domains which can be used to perform Facebook Login on behalf of your app.